# run() method is not waiting for data input

Tags: java, server, client

I'm trying to make an application into which you input two numbers, the numbers get parsed and sent off to the server via TCP protocol and then added, returned back, and set to a TextField. The problem is, the run() method isn't waiting for the numbers to be inputed, unlike BufferedReader streams. I'm currently working with DataInputStream and DataOutPutStream.

Here's the code below!

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
         public Server(){

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1000);
                    Socket sSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sSocket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sSocket.getOutputStream()))
            {
                System.out.println("Client connected.");
                Integer s1 = in.read();
                Integer s2 = in.read();
                Integer result = s1 + s2;
                out.write(result);



            }
            catch(IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the Client class:

```
bs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ke) {

           n1 = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
           n2 = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
           tf1.setText(String.valueOf(n1));
           tf2.setText(String.valueOf(n2));


                  }
   });

      }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try(Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1000);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()))

            {
    out.write(n1);
    out.write(n2);
    Integer rezultat = in.read();
    tf3.setText(String.valueOf(result));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

        } 
    }
```

And I'm starting both via the main class and Threads.
Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: Which `run()` method - the one in the Client? If so, how and when are you starting it?

Comment: The integers get assigned the default value of 0 when I run the project because the run() method in the Server class isn't waiting for me to input the values and press the button... I'm starting both of the classes via Threads in the main class.

Comment: The problem is probably in the code you didn't post. The idea is: the server opens one ServerSocket - only once, not in a loop - and accepts connections - in a loop. If you see "Client connected" on the server side, then your client has connected, meaning the `run` method in the client has executed. My understanding is that your client has a button besides the 2 text fields, and you intend that when you press it, the server is contacted to perform the addition? If this is the case, you don't want to start the client thread in `main`, but in the event handler for the button press.

Comment: The is exactly what I wish to do. I'm now working on the solution. Thank you! :D

Comment: I have done so. The ServerSocket is outside the run() method so that it can connect with the Client upon initializing the Client, however, I'm not very sure where should I put the ServerSocket... If I put it in the constructor, and then call the run() method from the ActionEvent, then the Bind is already being used since the the Client is already connected with the server...

Comment: Here's a pastie link to the whole code! 
http://pastie.org/private/ibgsodknsk8i9tyofssdq
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only needs a few changes to fix this: first, in your main, replace

```
    Thread clientThread = new Thread( new Klijent() );
    clientThread.start();
```

with

```
    Thread serverThread = new Thread( new Server() );
    serverThread.start(); 
    new Klijent();
```

You'll want the server in the background, and not run the code in the button event handler - the server should be able to run as a separate program.

Second, in the `Klijent` constructor, remove

```
    Server s = new Server();
```

from the constructor, since it is now done in `main`, and replace

```
            s.run();
```

with

```
            run();
```

to call the client's run method, instead of the server's.

---

If the assignment says to use a client thread to make the request, you could also add a second thread in your button event handler:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ke) {
        n1 = ...
        n2 = ...
        new Thread(Klijent.this).start(); // instead of this.run();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!
This finally helped me! :)
The program is working now. I owe you one ;)